# A Matrix such that its Square in Negative of the Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $A$ be an $2n$ by $2n$ matrix such that $A^2 = -I_{2n}$. Prove that $A$ is similar to the matrix
>   \begin{equation}
>      \left( \array{0 && -I_n \\ I_n && 0} \right).
> \end{equation}

I have no idea how to start this problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with eigenvalues?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I am.

Comment: @user109871 to what extent are you familiar with them?

Comment: Can you ay anything useful about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Apparently, I am not familiar with the enough.

Comment: Shouldn't we be referring to eigenvalues  and _eigenvectors_? Seems like eigenvalues alone may not cut it.

Answer (score 2):

This is only true over fields such as $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ in which the equation $x^2=-1$ is not soluble. Over the complex numbers, $A=iI$ satisfies $A^2=-I$ but is not similar to the given matrix.

Over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$ though, the condition $A^2=-I$ means that the rational
canonical form of $A$ is uniquely defined, so all matrices $A$ with $A^2=-I$ are similar.